# grunt-browserify failing when pushing to heroku using heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt

Tags: angularjs, heroku, gruntjs, bower

I am tryng to deploy my app to heroku. Everything seems to work at first, node packages being installed and all, but then grunt fails to resolve a 'require('angular')'.

I am suspecting that the transformify thing is failing and therefore the path to angular is unknown?

Or do I need to add angular specifically to the package.json? I am confused that it works locally.

```
Running "browserify:dist" (browserify) task
>> Error: ENOENT, open '/tmp/build_001656dd-4d72-40f4-b89a-b6bb75190d23/bower_components/angular/angular.js' while resolving "angular" from file /tmp/build_001656dd-4d72-40f4-b89a-b6bb75190d23/sections/_default/angular-app.js
Warning: Error running grunt-browserify. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

My gruntfile:

```
/* jslint node: true */
'use strict';
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  var transformify = require('transformify');
  var requires = require('./sections/_default/browser-requires.js')();


  var addRequires = transformify(function (x) {
    return x.replace('/* modules browserify */', requires);
  });
    // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg     : grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jshint  : {
      all     : [ 'Gruntfile.js', 'index.js', 'sections/**/*.js' ]
    },
    browserify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'static/js/app.js': ['sections/_default/angular-app.js']
        },
        options: {
          transform: [ addRequires, 'browserify-shim']
        }
      }
    },
    uglify  : {
      target : {
        files : { 'static/js/app.min.js' : 'static/js/app.js' }
      },
      options: {
        mangle: false
      }
    },
    clean : [ 'static/js/app.js' ]
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');


    // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', [
      'jshint',
      'browserify',
      'uglify',
      'clean'
    ]
  );

  grunt.registerTask('heroku', [
      'jshint',
      'browserify',
      'uglify',
      'clean'
    ]
  );

};
```

Below is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "developdavid",
  "version": "0.0.0-7",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.2.6",
    "jade": "~0.31.2",
    "di": "0.0.1",
    "transformify": "~0.1.2",
    "express-less": "0.0.2",
    "browserify": "~3.28.1",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.3.1",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "monk": "*",
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
    "grunt-browserify": "^1.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "angular": "./bower_components/angular/angular.js",
    "bootstrap": "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "angular-resource": "./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js",
    "angular-route": "./bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js",
    "angular-bootstrap": "./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
    "angular-animate": "./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js",
    "angular-sanitize": "./bower_components/textAngular/src/textAngular-sanitize.js",
    "text-angular-setup": "./bower_components/textAngular/src/textAngularSetup.js",
    "text-angular": "./bower_components/textAngular/src/textAngular.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "angular": {
      "exports": "angular",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$"
      ]
    },
    "text-angular-setup": {
      "depends": [
        "angular:angular"
      ]
    },
    "text-angular": {
      "depends": [
        "angular:angular"
      ]
    },
    "angular-sanitize": {
      "depends": [
        "angular:angular"
      ]
    },
    "angular-bootstrap": {
      "depends": [
        "angular:angular"
      ]
    },
    "angular-animate": {
      "depends": [
        "angular:angular"
      ]
    },
    "angular-resource": {
      "depends": [
        "angular:angular"
      ]
    },
    "angular-route": {
      "depends": [
        "angular:angular"
      ]
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$"
      ]
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
    "grunt-browserify": "^1.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0"
  },
  "subdomain": "developDavid",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x"
  }
}
```

Also my 'browser-requires' used by the grunt file:

```
/* jslint node: true */
'use strict';
var fs            = require('fs');

module.exports = function () {
  var requires = [];
  fs.readdirSync('./sections/').forEach(function (file) {
    var fullpath    = './sections/' + file,
        isDirectory = fs.lstatSync(fullpath).isDirectory();
    if (isDirectory && file !== '_default') {
      var dir = file;
      fs.readdirSync('./sections/' + dir).forEach(function (file) {
        if (/.*\.browser.js$/.test(file)) {
          requires.push('injector.invoke(require(\'../' + dir + '/' + file + '\'));');
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return requires.join('');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly fix:

Just added bower_components to the commit and then all files where found on heroku. Maybe they install the bower components in a different folder or something... 
In that case i should have two now I guess.